# catch_config_error while trying to run ipython3

Tags: pip, ipython

I'm getting the following error trying to run `ipython3`.

> catch_config_error() missing 1 required positional argument: 'app'

I first got it on my *Mac* (`python36`). As my system has all sorts of customizations, I tried  it again on a *Linux* system (*Centos 7.4*). I install *ipython* using *pip3* and everything seemed to install cleanly. (On the same system, if i do this with python2, it seems to work.

Complete error log:

```
[scott] ipython3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/ipython3", line 7, in <module>
    from IPython import start_ipython
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 54, in <module>
    from .core.application import Application
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/core/application.py", line 23, in <module>
    from traitlets.config.application import Application, catch_config_error
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/traitlets/config/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .application import *
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 120, in <module>
    class Application(SingletonConfigurable):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 291, in Application
    def initialize(self, argv=None):
TypeError: catch_config_error() missing 1 required positional argument: 'app'
```

Answer (score 4):

This is happening because traitlets relies on a package called 'decorator' that was just updated from 4.1.2 to 4.2.0 and broken its backward compatibility.

If you're using a requirements file or pip, install decorator==4.1.2 before installing IPython.

Answer (score 0):

I tried in Ubuntu 16.04.
I also had the same problem (Python 3.6)
I tried again today. 

`$ sudo -H pip3 install --upgrade ipython`

Then, decorator 4.2.1 is newly installed and the problem is solved.